# Image gets cut off when adjusting height

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

When I change height of The page the image starts to get cut off. I have attached a picture. This is the code I am using for the component which displays the picture. How could I make it responsive to shrink when the height is changed in tailwind

```html
<div class="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen py-48">
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap">
      <div class="w-full px-4">
        <div className="textColorHead banner header2">
          <div className="banner-text">
            <h1 className="responsive-headline">hi</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex  flex-col w-50 ">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="flex-col rounded-2xl drop-shadow-md hover:drop-shadow-xl transition-all duration-200 delay-100 flex-shrink-1" src="images/img.jpg" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2iCP.jpg)

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: then create a working snippet with tailwind

Comment: Try using `object-contain` on img tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should [use](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) `object-fit: contain;` in your img object if you want to display the image entirely or `object-fit: cover;` if you want to cover the empty space in every screen size. Example:

```css
div {
  max-width: 800px;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>This image is 1920x1080 pixels in a 800px box.</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that’s what I was looking for

Comment: and this is tailwind specific css classes for object-cover and fit https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-fit#basic-usage